# Survey questionnaire rebasing after removal of a selection

Tags: survey

Suppose that I have a market research survey with the question "What brand of television are you planning on buying" and then also have a choice that is "I don't plan on buying a television."  Respondents may choose more than one brand, but they may not make any other choices if they select that they do not plan on buying a television.

**If I wanted to do an analysis of television brands among only those people who said they were going to buy a television, can I remove all of the respondents that said they would not buy a television, then recalculate the proportions for each brand with the new base number of observations?**

If this skews the demographic distribution of my sample, is that okay? (e.g. the full sample has 30% Caucasians and 10% Asians, but the sample of people who say they will buy televisions is 30% Asians and 10% Caucasians.  It seems like this should be okay, since we would not expect the two populations (TV buyers and people in general) to be the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The short answer:** what you propose to do sounds reasonable.

It often occurs in survey research that a question only applies to a subset of the population.
In such situations you typically want to say:

- "Of American/Australian/French/etc. adults where this question is applicable, $X\%$ believes/intends to do/thinks/etc. ..."

**Representative:** As you say, in survey research you are often concerned with your findings being representative of a target population. If we assume that your initial sample is representative, then taking just the subset that intend to buy a television will be a representative sample of your population that intends to buy a television. This is true even if the subset that intends to buy a television is different to the subset that does not intend to buy a television in terms of demographics or some other factor in addition
to television purchasing intention.

In addition, you may want to produce cross-tabulations of purchase intention with demographics.

**Split Question**: I suppose you also need to think about what is the best split-question. Consumers vary in the degree to which they are intending to purchase a television and the degree to which they have thought about brands. Thus, you need to think about your research question. For example, you might ask the question: "if you were going to purchase a television, which brand would you consider?" This would be good for assessing longer term  brand purchasing intentions. Your structure focuses on the subset of consumers who are planning to purhcase.

Comment: I would put it: "Of the X% American/Australian/French/etc. adults who intend to buy a television, Y% intends to buy brand A, Z% intend to buy brand B,..." So you immediately see both information in one sentence.

Comment: @Henrik. Thanks. I agree. I guess I was trying to put it in slightly more general terms.

Comment: He should make sure the sample size from the new group is not too small however

Comment: @Neil. Good point.